# Flexbox dynamic size of images

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I started testing Flexbox using on an existing template from an older stackoverflow question. So, I am trying to make the image size to change in order to fit in parent div.

I have added this line in the HTML:

```
max-width: 50px; height: auto; margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; width: 100%; margin-left: .5rem;
```

for each `img` but if I change the screen size, it does not always look good. I tried playing with the paddings but the image gets cut in some cases.

```css
.row,.row.reverse{-webkit-box-orient:horizontal}.row{align-items:center}.min{min-height:220px}.min2{min-height:110px}.box-nested .left{text-align:left}.container{display:flex;align-items:center}.col-xs{-webkit-flex-grow:1}@media only screen and (min-width:48em){.container{width:46rem}.col-sm,.col-sm-1,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-sm{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-sm-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.333%;flex-basis:8.333%;max-width:8.333%}.col-sm-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-sm-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-sm-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-sm-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.667%;flex-basis:41.667%;max-width:41.667%}.col-sm-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-sm-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.333%;flex-basis:58.333%;max-width:58.333%}.col-sm-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.667%;flex-basis:66.667%;max-width:66.667%}.col-sm-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-sm-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-sm-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.667%;flex-basis:91.667%;max-width:91.667%}.col-sm-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left:8.333%}.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left:16.667%}.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left:33.333%}.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left:41.667%}.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left:58.333%}.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left:66.667%}.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left:83.333%}.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left:91.667%}.start-sm{-ms-flex-pack:start;-webkit-box-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-sm{-ms-flex-pack:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-sm{-ms-flex-pack:end;-webkit-box-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-sm{-ms-flex-align:start;-webkit-box-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-sm{-ms-flex-align:center;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-sm{-ms-flex-align:end;-webkit-box-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-sm{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-sm{-ms-flex-pack:justify;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-sm{-ms-flex-order:-1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;order:-1}.last-sm{-ms-flex-order:1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:62em){.container{width:61rem}.col-md,.col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-md{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-md-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.333%;flex-basis:8.333%;max-width:8.333%}.col-md-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-md-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-md-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-md-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.667%;flex-basis:41.667%;max-width:41.667%}.col-md-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-md-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.333%;flex-basis:58.333%;max-width:58.333%}.col-md-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.667%;flex-basis:66.667%;max-width:66.667%}.col-md-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-md-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-md-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.667%;flex-basis:91.667%;max-width:91.667%}.col-md-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-md-offset-1{margin-left:8.333%}.col-md-offset-2{margin-left:16.667%}.col-md-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-md-offset-4{margin-left:33.333%}.col-md-offset-5{margin-left:41.667%}.col-md-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-md-offset-7{margin-left:58.333%}.col-md-offset-8{margin-left:66.667%}.col-md-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-md-offset-10{margin-left:83.333%}.col-md-offset-11{margin-left:91.667%}.start-md{-ms-flex-pack:start;-webkit-box-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-md{-ms-flex-pack:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-md{-ms-flex-pack:end;-webkit-box-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-md{-ms-flex-align:start;-webkit-box-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-md{-ms-flex-align:center;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-md{-ms-flex-align:end;-webkit-box-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-md{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-md{-ms-flex-pack:justify;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-md{-ms-flex-order:-1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;order:-1}.last-md{-ms-flex-order:1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:75em){.container{width:71rem}.col-lg,.col-lg-1,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-lg{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-lg-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.333%;flex-basis:8.333%;max-width:8.333%}.col-lg-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-lg-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-lg-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-lg-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.667%;flex-basis:41.667%;max-width:41.667%}.col-lg-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-lg-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.333%;flex-basis:58.333%;max-width:58.333%}.col-lg-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.667%;flex-basis:66.667%;max-width:66.667%}.col-lg-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-lg-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-lg-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.667%;flex-basis:91.667%;max-width:91.667%}.col-lg-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left:8.333%}.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left:16.667%}.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left:33.333%}.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left:41.667%}.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left:58.333%}.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left:66.667%}.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left:83.333%}.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left:91.667%}.start-lg{-ms-flex-pack:start;-webkit-box-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-lg{-ms-flex-pack:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-lg{-ms-flex-pack:end;-webkit-box-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-lg{-ms-flex-align:start;-webkit-box-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-lg{-ms-flex-align:center;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-lg{-ms-flex-align:end;-webkit-box-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-lg{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-lg{-ms-flex-pack:justify;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-lg{-ms-flex-order:-1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;order:-1}.last-lg{-ms-flex-order:1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;order:1}}/*! normalize.css v2.1.3 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}a{background:0 0}a:focus{outline:dotted thin}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}.tag,body{font-weight:400}dfn{font-style:italic}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}.box,.box-container,.box-first,.box-large,.box-nested,.box-row,.page-footer,.row,body{box-sizing:border-box}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;font-size:1em}pre{white-space:pre-wrap}q{quotes:"\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}body{padding:0;margin:0;font-size:1rem;font-family:HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;background:#EEE;line-height:1.4rem}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:Gibson,HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;color:#001A33}h2{font-size:2rem;margin:1rem 0}:focus{outline-color:transparent;outline-style:none}h2+p{margin:0 0 2rem}.box,.box-first,.box-large,.box-nested,.box-row{position:relative;min-height:1rem;margin-bottom:0;background:#007FFF;////border:1px solid #FFF;border-radius:2px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;color:#fff}.box-row{margin-bottom:1rem}.box-first{background:#06C;border-color:#007FFF}.box-nested{////background:#036;////border-color:#007FFF}.box-large{height:8rem}.box-container{padding:.2rem}.page-footer{padding-bottom:3rem}.tag{color:#000}.end{text-align:end}.invisible-xs{display:none;visibility:hidden}.visible-xs{display:block;visibility:visible}@media only screen and (min-width:48rem){body{font-size:16px}.box,.box-first,.box-large,.box-nested,.box-row{////padding:1rem}.invisible-md{display:none;visibility:hidden}.visible-md{display:block;visibility:visible}}.container,.container-fluid{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}.container-fluid{padding-right:2rem;padding-left:2rem}.row{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 1 auto;flex:0 1 auto;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-right:-.5rem;margin-left:-.5rem}.col.reverse,.row.reverse{-webkit-box-direction:reverse}.row.reverse{-ms-flex-direction:row-reverse;flex-direction:row-reverse}.col.reverse{-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-ms-flex-direction:column-reverse;flex-direction:column-reverse}.col-xs,.col-xs-1,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-11,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-3,.col-xs-4,.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7,.col-xs-8,.col-xs-9,.col-xs-offset-0,.col-xs-offset-1,.col-xs-offset-10,.col-xs-offset-11,.col-xs-offset-12,.col-xs-offset-2,.col-xs-offset-3,.col-xs-offset-4,.col-xs-offset-5,.col-xs-offset-6,.col-xs-offset-7,.col-xs-offset-8,.col-xs-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.2rem;padding-left:.2rem}.col-xs{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-xs-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-xs-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-xs-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-xs-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-xs-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-xs-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-xs-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-xs-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-xs-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-xs-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-xs-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-xs-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-xs-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-xs-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-xs-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-xs-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-xs-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-xs{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-xs{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-xs{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-xs{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-xs{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-xs{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-xs{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-xs{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-xs{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-xs{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}@media only screen and (min-width:48em){.container{width:49rem}.col-sm,.col-sm-1,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9,.col-sm-offset-0,.col-sm-offset-1,.col-sm-offset-10,.col-sm-offset-11,.col-sm-offset-12,.col-sm-offset-2,.col-sm-offset-3,.col-sm-offset-4,.col-sm-offset-5,.col-sm-offset-6,.col-sm-offset-7,.col-sm-offset-8,.col-sm-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-sm{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-sm-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-sm-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-sm-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-sm-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-sm-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-sm-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-sm-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-sm-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-sm-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-sm-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-sm-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-sm-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-sm-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-sm{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-sm{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-sm{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-sm{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-sm{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-sm{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-sm{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-sm{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-sm{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-sm{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:64em){.container{width:65rem}.col-md,.col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-offset-0,.col-md-offset-1,.col-md-offset-10,.col-md-offset-11,.col-md-offset-12,.col-md-offset-2,.col-md-offset-3,.col-md-offset-4,.col-md-offset-5,.col-md-offset-6,.col-md-offset-7,.col-md-offset-8,.col-md-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-md{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-md-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-md-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-md-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-md-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-md-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-md-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-md-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-md-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-md-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-md-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-md-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-md-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-md-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-md-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-md-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-md-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-md-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-md-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-md-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-md-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-md-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-md-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-md-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-md-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-md{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-md{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-md{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-md{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-md{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-md{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-md{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-md{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-md{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-md{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:75em){.container{width:76rem}.col-lg,.col-lg-1,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9,.col-lg-offset-0,.col-lg-offset-1,.col-lg-offset-10,.col-lg-offset-11,.col-lg-offset-12,.col-lg-offset-2,.col-lg-offset-3,.col-lg-offset-4,.col-lg-offset-5,.col-lg-offset-6,.col-lg-offset-7,.col-lg-offset-8,.col-lg-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-lg{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-lg-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-lg-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-lg-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-lg-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-lg-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-lg-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-lg-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-lg-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-lg-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-lg-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-lg-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-lg-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-lg-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-lg{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-lg{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-lg{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-lg{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-lg{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-lg{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-lg{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-lg{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-lg{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-lg{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box box-container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row ">
                     <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="box-nested">

        <!-- First Box -->
        <div class="row min">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box-nested">
          <img style="max-width: 50px; height: auto; margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; width: 100%; margin-left: .5rem;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicity/512/dollar-256.png"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">AAA</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">111</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">AAA</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">111</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /First Box -->

                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- Second Box -->
                     <div class="col-xs-4 ">
      <div class="box-nested">            

   
        
        <div class="row min2">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box-nested">
          <img style="max-width: 50px; height: auto; margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; width: 100%; margin-left: .5rem;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicity/512/dollar-256.png"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row min2">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box-nested">
          <img style="max-width: 50px; height: auto; margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; width: 100%; margin-left: .5rem;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicity/512/dollar-256.png"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
                    
                                    
                          </div>   
                     </div>
      <!-- /Second Box -->
      
      <!-- Third Box-->
                     <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="box-nested"> 
       <div class="row min">      
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="box-nested">            
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-nested left">CCC</div>
            <div class="box-nested left">333</div>
          </div>
         </div>   
         <div class="box-nested">            
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-nested left">C3C3C3</div>
          </div>
         </div>       
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /Third Box-->
      

                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is stemming from using `margin-left` and width on the image element. When you do this the image gets the full width of the element but is pushed to the side by the margin and you get the clipping you see.

There are a few fixes for this. You can move the margin style to the parent element (as in my example snippet below). Or as long as you are in a modern browser you can set the width using `calc` which allows you to mix width types (`width: calc(100% - .5rem);`).

Note: The `.row` class has `margin-right` and `margin-left` set to `-.5rem` which is what causes the whole row to clip on the left and right (I'm assuming you have the area not at full page width in your implementation so you shouldn't have this issue). I've commented those two lines out in below though.

```css
.row,.row.reverse{-webkit-box-orient:horizontal}.row{align-items:center}.min{min-height:220px}.min2{min-height:110px}.box-nested .left{text-align:left}.container{display:flex;align-items:center}.col-xs{-webkit-flex-grow:1}@media only screen and (min-width:48em){.container{width:46rem}.col-sm,.col-sm-1,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-sm{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-sm-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.333%;flex-basis:8.333%;max-width:8.333%}.col-sm-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-sm-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-sm-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-sm-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.667%;flex-basis:41.667%;max-width:41.667%}.col-sm-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-sm-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.333%;flex-basis:58.333%;max-width:58.333%}.col-sm-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.667%;flex-basis:66.667%;max-width:66.667%}.col-sm-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-sm-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-sm-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.667%;flex-basis:91.667%;max-width:91.667%}.col-sm-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left:8.333%}.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left:16.667%}.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left:33.333%}.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left:41.667%}.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left:58.333%}.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left:66.667%}.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left:83.333%}.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left:91.667%}.start-sm{-ms-flex-pack:start;-webkit-box-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-sm{-ms-flex-pack:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-sm{-ms-flex-pack:end;-webkit-box-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-sm{-ms-flex-align:start;-webkit-box-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-sm{-ms-flex-align:center;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-sm{-ms-flex-align:end;-webkit-box-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-sm{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-sm{-ms-flex-pack:justify;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-sm{-ms-flex-order:-1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;order:-1}.last-sm{-ms-flex-order:1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:62em){.container{width:61rem}.col-md,.col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-md{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-md-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.333%;flex-basis:8.333%;max-width:8.333%}.col-md-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-md-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-md-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-md-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.667%;flex-basis:41.667%;max-width:41.667%}.col-md-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-md-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.333%;flex-basis:58.333%;max-width:58.333%}.col-md-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.667%;flex-basis:66.667%;max-width:66.667%}.col-md-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-md-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-md-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.667%;flex-basis:91.667%;max-width:91.667%}.col-md-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-md-offset-1{margin-left:8.333%}.col-md-offset-2{margin-left:16.667%}.col-md-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-md-offset-4{margin-left:33.333%}.col-md-offset-5{margin-left:41.667%}.col-md-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-md-offset-7{margin-left:58.333%}.col-md-offset-8{margin-left:66.667%}.col-md-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-md-offset-10{margin-left:83.333%}.col-md-offset-11{margin-left:91.667%}.start-md{-ms-flex-pack:start;-webkit-box-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-md{-ms-flex-pack:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-md{-ms-flex-pack:end;-webkit-box-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-md{-ms-flex-align:start;-webkit-box-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-md{-ms-flex-align:center;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-md{-ms-flex-align:end;-webkit-box-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-md{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-md{-ms-flex-pack:justify;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-md{-ms-flex-order:-1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;order:-1}.last-md{-ms-flex-order:1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:75em){.container{width:71rem}.col-lg,.col-lg-1,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-lg{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-lg-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.333%;flex-basis:8.333%;max-width:8.333%}.col-lg-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-lg-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-lg-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-lg-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.667%;flex-basis:41.667%;max-width:41.667%}.col-lg-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-lg-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.333%;flex-basis:58.333%;max-width:58.333%}.col-lg-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.667%;flex-basis:66.667%;max-width:66.667%}.col-lg-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-lg-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-lg-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.667%;flex-basis:91.667%;max-width:91.667%}.col-lg-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left:8.333%}.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left:16.667%}.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left:33.333%}.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left:41.667%}.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left:58.333%}.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left:66.667%}.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left:83.333%}.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left:91.667%}.start-lg{-ms-flex-pack:start;-webkit-box-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-lg{-ms-flex-pack:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-lg{-ms-flex-pack:end;-webkit-box-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-lg{-ms-flex-align:start;-webkit-box-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-lg{-ms-flex-align:center;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-lg{-ms-flex-align:end;-webkit-box-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-lg{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-lg{-ms-flex-pack:justify;-webkit-box-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-lg{-ms-flex-order:-1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;order:-1}.last-lg{-ms-flex-order:1;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;order:1}}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}a{background:0 0}a:focus{outline:dotted thin}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}.tag,body{font-weight:400}dfn{font-style:italic}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}.box,.box-container,.box-first,.box-large,.box-nested,.box-row,.page-footer,.row,body{box-sizing:border-box}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;font-size:1em}pre{white-space:pre-wrap}q{quotes:"“" "”" "‘" "’"}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}body{padding:0;margin:0;font-size:1rem;font-family:HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;background:#eee;line-height:1.4rem}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:Gibson,HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;color:#001a33}h2{font-size:2rem;margin:1rem 0}:focus{outline-color:transparent;outline-style:none}h2+p{margin:0 0 2rem}.box,.box-first,.box-large,.box-nested,.box-row{position:relative;min-height:1rem;margin-bottom:0;background:#007fff;border-radius:2px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;color:#fff}.box-row{margin-bottom:1rem}.box-first{background:#06c;border-color:#007fff}.box-nested{}.box-large{height:8rem}.box-container{padding:.2rem}.page-footer{padding-bottom:3rem}.tag{color:#000}.end{text-align:end}.invisible-xs{display:none;visibility:hidden}.visible-xs{display:block;visibility:visible}@media only screen and (min-width:48rem){body{font-size:16px}.box,.box-first,.box-large,.box-nested,.box-row{}.invisible-md{display:none;visibility:hidden}.visible-md{display:block;visibility:visible}}.container,.container-fluid{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}.container-fluid{padding-right:2rem;padding-left:2rem}.row{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 1 auto;flex:0 1 auto;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap}.col.reverse,.row.reverse{-webkit-box-direction:reverse}.row.reverse{-ms-flex-direction:row-reverse;flex-direction:row-reverse}.col.reverse{-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-ms-flex-direction:column-reverse;flex-direction:column-reverse}.col-xs,.col-xs-1,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-11,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-3,.col-xs-4,.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7,.col-xs-8,.col-xs-9,.col-xs-offset-0,.col-xs-offset-1,.col-xs-offset-10,.col-xs-offset-11,.col-xs-offset-12,.col-xs-offset-2,.col-xs-offset-3,.col-xs-offset-4,.col-xs-offset-5,.col-xs-offset-6,.col-xs-offset-7,.col-xs-offset-8,.col-xs-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.2rem;padding-left:.2rem}.col-xs{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-xs-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-xs-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-xs-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-xs-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-xs-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-xs-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-xs-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-xs-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-xs-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-xs-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-xs-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-xs-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-xs-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-xs-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-xs-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-xs-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-xs-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-xs{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-xs{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-xs{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-xs{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-xs{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-xs{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-xs{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-xs{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-xs{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-xs{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}@media only screen and (min-width:48em){.container{width:49rem}.col-sm,.col-sm-1,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9,.col-sm-offset-0,.col-sm-offset-1,.col-sm-offset-10,.col-sm-offset-11,.col-sm-offset-12,.col-sm-offset-2,.col-sm-offset-3,.col-sm-offset-4,.col-sm-offset-5,.col-sm-offset-6,.col-sm-offset-7,.col-sm-offset-8,.col-sm-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-sm{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-sm-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-sm-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-sm-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-sm-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-sm-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-sm-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-sm-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-sm-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-sm-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-sm-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-sm-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-sm-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-sm-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-sm{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-sm{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-sm{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-sm{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-sm{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-sm{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-sm{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-sm{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-sm{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-sm{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:64em){.container{width:65rem}.col-md,.col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-offset-0,.col-md-offset-1,.col-md-offset-10,.col-md-offset-11,.col-md-offset-12,.col-md-offset-2,.col-md-offset-3,.col-md-offset-4,.col-md-offset-5,.col-md-offset-6,.col-md-offset-7,.col-md-offset-8,.col-md-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-md{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-md-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-md-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-md-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-md-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-md-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-md-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-md-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-md-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-md-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-md-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-md-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-md-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-md-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-md-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-md-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-md-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-md-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-md-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-md-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-md-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-md-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-md-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-md-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-md-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-md{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-md{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-md{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-md{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-md{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-md{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-md{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-md{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-md{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-md{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}}@media only screen and (min-width:75em){.container{width:76rem}.col-lg,.col-lg-1,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9,.col-lg-offset-0,.col-lg-offset-1,.col-lg-offset-10,.col-lg-offset-11,.col-lg-offset-12,.col-lg-offset-2,.col-lg-offset-3,.col-lg-offset-4,.col-lg-offset-5,.col-lg-offset-6,.col-lg-offset-7,.col-lg-offset-8,.col-lg-offset-9{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-lg{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-lg-1{-ms-flex-preferred-size:8.33333333%;flex-basis:8.33333333%;max-width:8.33333333%}.col-lg-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-lg-3{-ms-flex-preferred-size:25%;flex-basis:25%;max-width:25%}.col-lg-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-lg-5{-ms-flex-preferred-size:41.66666667%;flex-basis:41.66666667%;max-width:41.66666667%}.col-lg-6{-ms-flex-preferred-size:50%;flex-basis:50%;max-width:50%}.col-lg-7{-ms-flex-preferred-size:58.33333333%;flex-basis:58.33333333%;max-width:58.33333333%}.col-lg-8{-ms-flex-preferred-size:66.66666667%;flex-basis:66.66666667%;max-width:66.66666667%}.col-lg-9{-ms-flex-preferred-size:75%;flex-basis:75%;max-width:75%}.col-lg-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-lg-11{-ms-flex-preferred-size:91.66666667%;flex-basis:91.66666667%;max-width:91.66666667%}.col-lg-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}.col-lg-offset-0{margin-left:0}.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.start-lg{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;text-align:start}.center-lg{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;text-align:center}.end-lg{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:end}.top-lg{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.middle-lg{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.bottom-lg{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.around-lg{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.between-lg{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.first-lg{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1}.last-lg{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box box-container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row ">
                     <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="box-nested">

        <!-- First Box -->
        <div class="row min">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box-nested" sytle="margin-left: .5rem;">
          <img style="max-width: 50px; height: auto; margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; width: 100%;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicity/512/dollar-256.png"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">AAA</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">111</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">AAA</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">111</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /First Box -->

                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- Second Box -->
                     <div class="col-xs-4 ">
      <div class="box-nested">            

   
        
        <div class="row min2">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box-nested" style="margin-left: .5rem;">
          <img style="max-width: 50px; height: auto; margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; width: 100%;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicity/512/dollar-256.png"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row min2">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box-nested" style="margin-left: .5rem;">
          <img style="max-width: 50px; height: auto; margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; width: 100%;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicity/512/dollar-256.png"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
           <div class="box-nested left">222</div>
           <div class="box-nested left">BBB</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
                    
                                    
                          </div>   
                     </div>
      <!-- /Second Box -->
      
      <!-- Third Box-->
                     <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="box-nested"> 
       <div class="row min">      
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="box-nested">            
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-nested left">CCC</div>
            <div class="box-nested left">333</div>
          </div>
         </div>   
         <div class="box-nested">            
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-nested left">C3C3C3</div>
          </div>
         </div>       
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /Third Box-->
      

                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works. I have another question. I will create a new question if you wanna have a look too. Interesting one :) Flexbox is amazing!

Comment: I have created a codepen with an additional column. I removed the margin-left values you added in the CSS. I am thinking of reducing the spaces though and making the rotated text column width smaller. I have raised a question where I cannot align the rotated text vertically.